# How can we call AJAX in Firefox

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I am making an AJAX call using the `XMLHttpRequest`.

It's working fine in IE7, but when i try the same in Firefox, I am not able to get it back thru the `response.write`

I am using the function below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function ddSelect_Change() {
          var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...       
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE       
                try {
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                }

                catch (e) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) 
                    {
                    }
                }
            }   

 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
}
}
 var url = "http://" + location.hostname + "Locationurl?Method=methodname";
xmlhttp.open("POST", url);
               xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

**ADDED**

I have two separate web application one is tridion web application and other is custom web application. and i am making interaction from tridion web application to custom web application. Both the url are having different domain.and state i am getting 0 in firefox, and for readystate i am not getting (3) in my alert.

Comment: What does the rest of your AJAX code look like?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson i am using rest codes like above .

Comment: Do you get any JS-errors? If you log your HTTP traffic using fiddler, is a call made to the server or not?

Comment: You may need to make sure your onreadystatechange function is defined before you call .send() (your explanation above doesn't make clear if you are doing this or not).

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown so far should work in Firefox. Firefox support XHR.

This might be at help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

**Update:**

`onreadystatechange` is fired several times during an AJAX call, so you probably want to extend your callback to something like this:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
      if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
```

`xmlhttp.readyState === 4` verifies that the request has completed, so that you don't try to alert the response before you actually have it. `xmlhttp.status === 200` verifies that you recieved a `200 OK` from the server, to make sure that there were no server-side errors, or that the URL was incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, i have used the same code suggested by you, but still i am not getting it functioned oin Firefox

Comment: @SDLBeginner Do you get any errors in Firefox? How is the AJAX-call triggered? Could it be that the code triggering the call doesn't work in Firefox? What happens if you just do: `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { alert(xmlhttp.readyState); }` Do you get any alerts at all then?

Comment: No when i am keeping just `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { alert(xmlhttp.readyState); }` i am getting 1 as first alert and 4 as second alert.I kept my edited code in question.

Comment: @SDLBeginner Okay, so then we know that the call is fired at least. If you extend it to `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) { alert(xmlhttp.status); }}` Do you then get `200` as your alert?

Comment: i changed the alert for Status , in IE i am getting alert as 200 but for firefox i am not getting alert as 200.

Comment: i am getting alert as 0 insteed of 200.

Comment: @SDLBeginner Could it be that you are either running your files locally (not through a web server), or that you are trying to do a cross-domain request? It seems like that could cause a status `0`

Comment: i am not running it locally, i have placed my file in tridion server. How can i enable this creoss-domain request for firefox?

Comment: @SDLBeginner Well, cross-domain requests aren't simply something you enable, for security reasons. But first, is the url you request on the same domain as the file you are running this script on, or not?

Comment: yes the url i am requesting  and the file both are in same domain.

Comment: @SDLBeginner Okay, so then it shouldn't be a cross-domain issue. Mozilla has a short note about status being set to `0`. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Using_XMLHttpRequest#XMLHttpRequests_being_stopped). Maybe that can help you in some way.

Comment: sorry i want to make a clarification here , i have two separate  web application one is tridion web application and other is custom web application. and i am making interaction from tridion web application to custom web application. Both the url are having different domain.and state i am getting 0 in firefox, and for readystate i am not getting (3) in my alert.

Comment: @SDLBeginner In that case, since you actually want to do cross-domain requests, you would have to look into [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), or [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a library like jQuery? It already has taken care of these issues for you.

If you are working on a SDL Tridion GUI extension, check out the PowerTools project for a ton of examples. (http://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/)